# Angular 1.5.x Component Router with loader (How to lazy load component?)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components

I am trying to use the new ComponentRouter in Angular 1.5x. I would like to lazy load a component for my $routerRootComponents.$routConfig. I have my top level component defined, but it's $routeConfig I would like to have Async Route definition.

Looking at the Angular2 documentation I just need to provide a promise that will resolve to a component. However, no access to $q from the app.config function. Also, I am not sure if the AngularJS 1.x promise will work since the NG2 docs talk about ES6 promise.